# Sequelize Associations Causing Sub-Query

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a feature within my application that acts as an activity feed with blog posts (similar to Tumblr). In the route for this page, my primary query is on my blog post table and I am joining tables containing additional meta information and comments to this table for a fully featured card for each blogpost. These tables are from my category (categorizing the post), topic (topic of interest), file (files/images) attached, and comment (commenting on post) table.

With my current query I am able to join all of these tables without any issue, but I run into an issue with my where clause associated with the parent query on the blog post. When the `file` and `comment` tables are joined there is a sub-query that occurs, which I believe is related to the type of associations between blog posts and those tables and somehow affecting the results.

**Provided are the Schema's and associations:**

**blog_post**

- blog_id
- date
- content
- category_id
- topic_id

*Associations*

- belongsTo(user, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
- belongsTo(category, { foreignKey: 'category_id' });
- belongsTo(topic, { foreignKey: 'topic_id' });
- hasMany(file, { foreignKey: 'blog_id' });
- hasMany(comment, { foreignKey: 'blog_id' });

**user**

- user_id
- first_name
- last_name
- organization_id

**category**

- category_id
- category

*Associations*

- hasMany(blog_post, { foreignKey: 'category_id'})

**topic**

- topic_id
- topic

*Associations*

- hasMany(blog_post, { foreignKey: 'topic_id'})

*File and Comment tables do not have associations within their Schema files related to this issue.*

**Provided is the query (Please not camel casing are aliased column names above)**

```
models.BlogPost.findAll({
            order: 'Date DESC',
            include: [{
                model: models.User,
                where: { organizationId: req.user.organizationId },
                attributes: ['userId', 'firstName', 'lastName'],
                required: false,
            },
            {
                model: models.Topic,
                attributes: ['topic'],
                required: false
            },
            {
                model: models.Category,
                attributes: ['category'],
                required: false
            },
            {
                model: models.File,
                attributes: ['file'],
                required: false
            },
            {
                model: models.Comment,
                include: [{
                    model: models.User,
                    attributes: ['userId','firstName', 'lastName']
                }],
                required: false
            }],
            limit: 10
        })
```

**UPDATE with Sub Query:**

```
SELECT `blog_post`.*, `user`.`user_id`, `user`.`first_name`, `user`.`last_name`, `topic`.`topic_id`, `topic`.`topic`, `category`.`category_id`, `category`.`category_name`, `file`.`file_id`, `file`.`file`, `comment`.`comment_id`, `comment`.`comment`, `comment`.`blog_id`, `comment`.`user_id`, `comment`.`created_at`, `comment`.`updated_at`, `comment`.`blog_id`, `comment`.`user_id`, `comment.user`.`user_id`
FROM (SELECT `blog_post.`blog_id`, `blog_post.`date`, `blog_post.`title`, `blog_post.`content`, `blog_post.`topic_id`, `blog_post.`category_id`, `blog_post.`user_id`, `blog_post.`created_at`, `blog_post.`updated_at`, `blog_post.`user_id`, `blog_post.`topic_id`, `blog_post.`category_id` FROM `blog_post LIMIT 10) AS `blog_post 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `user` AS `user` ON `blog_post.`user_id` = `user`.`user_id` AND `user`.`organization_id` = 1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `topic` AS `topic` ON `blog_post.`topic_id` = `topic`.`topic_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `category` AS `category` ON `blog_post.`category_id` = `category`.`category_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `file` AS `file` ON `blog_post.`blog_id` = `file`.`blog_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `comment` AS `comment` ON `blog_post.`blog_id` = `comment`.`blog_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `user` AS `comment.user` ON `comment`.`user_id` = `comment.user`.`user_id` 
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Comment: What sub-query do you get? Can you paste the generated SQL?

Comment: @piotrbienias I added the generated SQL

Comment: See the answer below and tell if it solves the problem

Answer (score 22):

You probably need to add `subQuery: false` in the `options` object of `findAll` method. However, this option is not present in sequelize documentation, you can find it in the [`source code`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/75841f3eb311a39b2113351006e6c3dfde78b136/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js#LC756). If it is not set, it defaults to `true` and causes addition of the sub-query you mentioned when the `LIMIT` option is present in query.

Comment: Wow I'm amazed that this isn't documented, great find! However, the results from eliminating the subquery appear to repeat records multiple times, which I'm trying to debug at the moment.

Comment: Back tracking on my original thoughts and based on the results of removing the sub-query, I think that the sub-query is not the issue related to my problem. The sub-query is actually allowing me to limit by the amount of blog_posts captured in the query and join the tables on that sub-query, which is the intended result, limit blog_posts records and attach the related information to those posts. This makes me think that including varying associations types is causing the issue. Does this sound logical?

Comment: After digging a bit deeper, the solution to my problem is to include the `order` property within the sub-query. Do you know how that is done?

Answer (score 1):

i was having the same issue. i used the **subQuery:false** with the where statement object.

like:--

```
{
include:[{model:childrens,attributes:['id','firstName']}],
where:{'$childrens.id$':12}
subQuery:false
}
```

but you need to keep in mind that if you are using inner table at the where statement 
then you will have to use like:--

```
where:{'$childrens.id$':12}
```

because if you don't use **'$'** it will create automatic like:

`abcd(main table).childrens.id=12`

so to check for id value on childerns id then you will 
have to use **'$'**.

That's. Hope it will work for you.